# Problemas con password authentication de Github

Tags: github

estoy intentando hacer un push a través de la consola para subir archivos a github, pero cdo lo hago me pide autenticarme con usuario y contraseña. Pero después me dice " Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead."
Ya hice el token, pero no sé como usarlo, porque no me lo pide en ningún momento.

Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: te lo esta diciendo; el metodo de autenticacion que estas usando fue apagado/cancelado/puesto como obsoleto en esa fecha

Comment: debes cambiar la forma en que te autenticas ...

Comment: Sí, eso lo entiendo. El tema es cómo cambio. No me da la opción de poner el token, cdo hago el push directamente me pide el usuario y después el password. Entonces, ¿dónde y cuándo pongo el token?

Comment: El token va donde antes iba el password

Comment: eso tienes que configurarlo en la aplicacion; antes de  ... no durante de ...

Comment: Cuando te pida la password, pegas el token. De todas formas es mucho más conveniente que generes un par de claves ssh en tu ordenador y subas la parte pública a github, y que cambies el protocolo de los repositorios remotos de https a ssh

Comment: Pegué el token y no funcionó. Acabo de crear la clave ssh, me lo sugirió un amigo. Supongo que ahora tendré que volver a probar a hacer el push y ver qué pasa. Cómo sería lo de cambiar los protocolos? Gracias.

Comment: Quizás la forma más sencilla sea entrar en la carpeta (oculta) llamada .git dentro de tu repositorio local y editar el fichero `config`, buscar la sección `[remote]` y cambiar la url que pone algo como `https://github.com/usuario/repo.git` por ` git@github.com:usuario/repo.git` (o lo que te sale en la web de github para ese repositorio cuando pulsas el botón verde "Code" y seleccionas la pestaña ssh)

Comment: Alguien debería colocar la receta para utilizar tokens (yo no los uso pero se que son una posibilidad).

Answer (score 0):

### Problema

remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para leer este texto primero entiende como leerlo

```
$instruccion
resultado
```

Como vemos en el cuadro anterior `$` es para comandos de linux, y lo que aparece debajo `es el resultado de este`

### Solución

Bueno vamos a comenzar con la solución

El problema es un error con la autenticación de github, para ello los pasos van a ser .

1. Vamos al directorio donde se encuentra tu clave de ssh GitHub .
2. Borramos las viejas claves (opcional: en caso de haberlas creado con anterioridad).

```
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ ls
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
$ rm id_rsa id_rsa.pub
```

Posteriormente creas una nueva clave pública

- Enter file in which to save the key (/home/ejemplo/.ssh/id_rsa): **presionar enter para dejar por default**
- Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): **presionar enter para dejar  sin contraseña la llave privada en tu computadora, si es una portatil, o estas en oficina, recomiendo crear una, de lo contrario, solo da enter, para cada vez que hagas commit no tengas que estarla escribiendo**

```
 ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/ejemplo/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/ejemplo/.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /home/ejemplo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:Y5Et33o3RYK+rhynan3fcxAWcahdsdsddfTiG7M ejemplo@ejemplo
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|     +o=.        |
|    o B. o       |
|. . .B. *..      |
|...o*.o++*       |
| + =.o.BSSoo      |
|  =ss o.=B.      |
| E   o .+..      |
|    . o ..       |
|     ..+.        |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

### Agregamos la clave privada a linux

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 195
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /home/ejemplo/.ssh/id_rsa (oracle@ejemplo)
```

- Agent pid , puede tener otro número, si sale un error es porque el servicio, no se levantó y tienes dos opciones, levantar el proceso manualmente, o volver a intentar este procedimeinto.

### Agregando a github

```
$   cat id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQCpGGLOn1Hd6SyLVznGAt3fJ02kmmn0AynUI7wSmw4JxOzScxSxJ+Ot4zG60inVqqycUrIcUjmbDnUMwBwWSzJXEEvgT1gqL/xZI1JHYU3TGC
```

El contenido obtenido de l anterior ejecución, es decir `ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1y` la tenemos que copiar  y la pegamos en

vamos a settins

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora vamos a `ssh and GPG`, damos click en `new ssh key`, agregamos lo que habíamos copiado de la llave pública y obtendrás  que ya esta agregada la clave `sha256:something` , obvio yo la borre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si todo salió correcto, ya puedes hacer clone o push a lo que quieras, saludos.